# On the functional limit of the derivative and interchanging limits

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following limit:

$$ L = \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{h \to 0} {f(x+h) -f(x) \over h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\lim_{x \to 0} {f(x+h) -f(x) \over h} = \lim_{h \to 0}{f(h) -f(0) \over h} = f'(0)$$

Can the limts be interchanged? If not, why not? If yes, why?

I am assuming:

$f$ is differentiable on an interval containing $0$ and if $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = L$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a bad one, and you won't easily find a way out. Use instead the MVT:
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = f'(\vartheta)
$$
for some $\vartheta$ between $0$ and $x$. Then let $x \to 0$ and use your assumption.

### Edit

Of course it *is* possibile to interchange the two limits: it is *exactly* what you should prove! Roughly speaking, you ought to show that the convergence
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)
$$
is uniform with respect to $x$. But, if you don't know the MVT, probably uniform convergence is unknown as well. It *does* follow from the MVT, however.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Exchanging limits is a very dangerous trick, and it is legitimate only under very restrictive assumptions. I do not know a direct proof...

Comment: Is your answer saying that the limits are not interchangeable? Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: I'm just saying that I don't know...

Comment: Okay I will change the question once more to eliminate confusion about what I am asking.